# SwiftUI and Combine

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm following a [video on the Firebase YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RUeW5rUcww). Starting around 27:45, the instructor is trying to set a variable based on a Boolean and ends up with the following code in `init(task: Task)`:

```
$task
    .map { task in
        task.isCompleted ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle"
    }
    .assign(to: \.completionStateIconName, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

This seems overly convoluted to me. First, I can't find documentation on using `.map` on a struct object, only on arrays, etc. Second, what is with this `&cancellables` thing? (It's defined as `private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()` before the `init{}`.) Third, why all this code, and not simply:

```
task.completionStateIconName = task.isCompleted ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle"
```

This seems to give the same result, but will there be something down the line that the first code fragment works, but the second doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$task` (with the `$` prefix) is a projected value of the `@Published` property wrapper, and it returns a variable of the type [`Published.Publisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published/publisher). In other words, its a Combine publisher, which publishes a value whenever the property - in this case `Task` - changes.

If you didn't learn about the Combine framework (or other reactive frameworks), this answer is definitely not going to be enough. At a high-level, a Combine publisher emits values, which you can transform through operators like `.map`, and eventually subscribe to, for example with `.sink` or `.assign`.

So, line-by-line:

```
// a publisher of Task values
$task 
  // next, transform Task into a String using its isCompleted property
  .map { task in
     task.isCompleted ? "circle.fill" : "circle"
  }
  // subscribe, by assigning the String value to the completionStateIconName prop
  .assign(to: \.completionStateIconName, on: self)
```

Now, the above returns an instance of `AnyCancellable`, which you need to retain while you want to receive the values. So you either need to store it directly as a property, or use `.store`  to add it to a `Set<AnyCancellable>` - a common approach.

---

So, why is it so convoluted? This is, presumably, built so that if `task` property ever changes, the Combine pipeline would update the `completionStateIconName` property.

If you just did:

```
completionStateIconName = task.isCompleted ? "circle.fill" : "circle"
```

that would assign the value just in the beginning.

---

That being said, in this particular case it might actually be unnecessarily too convoluted to use Combine, whereas just using `didSet`:

```
var task: Task {
   didSet {
      completionStateIconName ? task.isCompleted ? "circle.fill" : "circle"
   }
}
```

Comment: Given that `Task` is a `struct`, the `didSet` would work fine. But so would a computed property, `var completionStateIconName: String { completionStateIconName ? task.isCompleted ? "circle.fill" : "circle" }`. And looking through the rest of the video, we can see that he doesn't even convert `TaskCell` to use `completionStateIconName`, so there's no reason to introduce that property at all!

Comment: @robmayoff, I haven't watched the full video, but yeah - seems like the use of Combine in that video is an unnecessary overkill, and because task is `@Published`, just using a computed property would work if it's consumed by a View.

Comment: @NewDev @rob Thank you. I forgot to propose my one-liner as part of a `didSet` or a computed value, but that was actually what I was thinking. 

Thanks for taking the time to answer so completely. I know *of* Combine, but certainly don't *know* it.

@rob I think you have an extra piece in your ternary expression, no? Don't you mean just `var completionStateIconName: String { task.isCompleted ? "circle.fill" : "circle" }`?

Comment: I'll continue this video and the follow-up videos and see if using Combine becomes necessary down the road...